# PHP JSON multiple echo value

Tags: php, arrays, json

In addition to the question yesterday: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937081/php-json-echo-specific-item/41937178)

I got multiple (3) Items in the json file:

results.json

```
["{\"Produkt\":{\"Produktkategorie\":\"Artikel1\",\"Optionen\":{\"MaxBreite\":\"250\",\"MaxHoehe\":\"150\",\"MinBreite\":\"10\",\"MinHoehe\":\"5\",\"ProduktStaerke\":\"3\",\"KantenAuswahl\":\"Kante1\"}}}","{\"Produkt\":{\"Produktkategorie\":\"Artikel2\",\"Optionen\":{\"MaxBreite\":\"250\",\"MaxHoehe\":\"150\",\"MinBreite\":\"10\",\"MinHoehe\":\"5\",\"ProduktStaerke\":\"3\",\"KantenAuswahl\":\"Kante2\"}}}","{\"Produkt\":{\"Produktkategorie\":\"Artikel3\",\"Optionen\":{\"MaxBreite\":\"250\",\"MaxHoehe\":\"150\",\"MinBreite\":\"10\",\"MinHoehe\":\"5\",\"ProduktStaerke\":\"3\",\"KantenAuswahl\":\"Kante3\"}}}"]
```

I want echo all three value from "Produktkategorie" and the value "MaxBreite"

It should look like this:

```
Artikel1 - 250
Artikel2 - 250
Artikel3 - 250
```

My code looks like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('results.json');
$json = json_decode($json, true);
$anzahl = count($json) -1;
$anzahlstart = 0;

while ($anzahlstart < $anzahl) {
$json = json_decode($json[$anzahlstart], true);                     
$ProduktkategorieFile = $json['Produkt']['Produktkategorie'];
$MaxBreiteFile = $json['Produkt']['Optionen']['MaxBreite'];                     
echo $ProduktkategorieFile. "-" .$MaxBreiteFile;
$anzahlstart ++; 
 }
```

Unfortunately my Code throws a error after passing first line:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in

After that I don't get any result.

Kings of coding, could you help me again please :)

Comment: Why are you using "json_decode" on the elements in the loop? it's already decoded... $anzahl is an object you can iterate in

Comment: the json is already decoded, your $json variable is an array after row 2

Comment: this was the solution yesterday, plz look at the link in the description, or you got a better solution? :)

Comment: also NEVER reassign the value of a variable within the loop, just remove the first row in the loop

Comment: wihout the second decoding it throws the error: Notice: Undefined index: Produkt in

Comment: ok then don'T double encode it in the first place, your POST is already a json, no need to encode it

Comment: Thank You i delete the double encoding in the save file :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do you need like this?:-**

```
<?php
$json_string = file_get_contents('results.json');
$json = json_decode($json_string, true); 
// I hope the above line gives you exact json what you shown to us

foreach ($json as $jso){
   $array = json_decode($jso, true);
   echo $array['Produkt']['Produktkategorie'].' - '.$array['Produkt']['Optionen']['MaxBreite'];
   echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/728430

***Note:- If yes then I hope you are able to get other values easily.Thanks***

Comment: Thank You this works for me, also the answer above :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the `$json` variable name: You're reassigning it on this line: `$json = json_decode($json[$anzahlstart], true);`

Rename this variable and you're good to go!

I would also replace the `while` loop with a `foreach` loop as shown in my example:

```
<?php
//With foreach
$original = '["{\"Produkt\":{\"Produktkategorie\":\"Artikel1\",\"Optionen\":{\"MaxBreite\":\"250\",\"MaxHoehe\":\"150\",\"MinBreite\":\"10\",\"MinHoehe\":\"5\",\"ProduktStaerke\":\"3\",\"KantenAuswahl\":\"Kante1\"}}}","{\"Produkt\":{\"Produktkategorie\":\"Artikel2\",\"Optionen\":{\"MaxBreite\":\"250\",\"MaxHoehe\":\"150\",\"MinBreite\":\"10\",\"MinHoehe\":\"5\",\"ProduktStaerke\":\"3\",\"KantenAuswahl\":\"Kante2\"}}}","{\"Produkt\":{\"Produktkategorie\":\"Artikel3\",\"Optionen\":{\"MaxBreite\":\"250\",\"MaxHoehe\":\"150\",\"MinBreite\":\"10\",\"MinHoehe\":\"5\",\"ProduktStaerke\":\"3\",\"KantenAuswahl\":\"Kante3\"}}}"]';
$decoded = json_decode($original);

foreach($decoded as $encodedProduct){
    $product = json_decode($encodedProduct,true)['Produkt'];
    echo $product['Produktkategorie'] . " - " . $product['Optionen']['MaxBreite'] . "\n";
}

//Original fixed code
$json = json_decode($original, true);
$anzahl = count($json);
$anzahlstart = 0;

while ($anzahlstart < $anzahl) {
    $decodedJson = json_decode($json[$anzahlstart], true);
    $ProduktkategorieFile = $decodedJson['Produkt']['Produktkategorie'];
    $MaxBreiteFile = $decodedJson['Produkt']['Optionen']['MaxBreite'];                     
    echo $ProduktkategorieFile. " - " .$MaxBreiteFile . "\n";
    $anzahlstart ++; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you are trying to decode an `array` of json `string`, instead of the `string` itself.

so that would be like this now.

```
$json = file_get_contents('results.json');
$json = json_decode($json[0], true); // notice [0];on this line.
...
```

After reading the other question, I have had this problem before, but you essentially need to do two things. in your ajax.

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   data : JSON.stringify(data)
})
```

This changes an object into a json string,

Then on your server you do the decode.

something like this

```
$json = json_decode($jsonstringGoesHERE , true);
```

For more information in understanding the issue, have a look at this other post.

[jQuery ajax, how to send JSON instead of QueryString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693947/jquery-ajax-how-to-send-json-instead-of-querystring)

Comment: This isn't the issue, he has 3 json strings in an array. He starts decoding the array, then decodes each inner json in a loop, but reassigned the `$json` variable which caused the error.

Comment: yes i'm a noob in working with json file, but your answer clears a bit for me thank you!

Comment: @Antony I would suggest, you read his `results.json` and that does not deserve a downvote,

Comment: @Val he initially decodes the json array, which contains 3 json strings, then loops through all of the values of the decoded array and decodes the inner string. He therefore is decoding the string itself, in the loop